# Polynomial $F$ with leading coefficient 1 such that $F(cosa)=cos(7a)$ for all $a$.

Tags: polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I got $$F(x)=64x^7-112x^5+56x^3-7x$$How do I convert this to a polynomial with leading coefficient 1?

I believe this problem is impossible because 2 different polynomials cannot be equal for all values. The exact statement of the problem as copied from the book:

"Find a polynomial $F(x)$ with leading coefficient 1 such that $F(\cos a)=\cos(7a)$ for any angle $a$."

If I'm right, I might've found a typo in my problem book.

Comment: You got it right. The condition $F_n(\cos\alpha)=\cos(n\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$ determines the polynomial $F_n$ uniquely. Its leading coefficient is $2^{n-1}$, and my guess is that whoever wrote the problem simply forgot that we don't have any freedom in the choice of polynomial (in particular no way to normalize the leading coefficient). These are well studied polynomials. See [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind) for a list and more.

Comment: They are not equal for all values since odd polynomials diverge to infinity and $\cos(x)$ is bounded. They can agree on arbitrarily many points in an interval if the relationship between $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(7x)$ is algebraic, in which case your polynomial is that relationship.

Comment: @law-of-fives The constraint $F(\cos\alpha)=\cos7\alpha$ specifies $F(x)$ only in the interval $x\in[-1,1]$, so I don't understand your point about the divergence of odd polynomials? Anyway, a polynomial is specified uniquely when we know its degree $\le n$ and its value at $n+1$ points.

Comment: This is a problem from Mu Alpha Theta 1992 which probably explains why they missed this mistake. The unusual thing is that the problem got put in a book and the authors also didn't catch the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Sure looks as if your polynomial is correct. (How likely is it that it'd work on $f(\cos(8) =\cos(56)$ without being correct?)

And your argument that if there were a monic polynomial $G$ with the same property, it'd have to equal $F$...that's pretty solid too, although it's not *quite* correct; what's true is that $G(x) = F(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$ (*all between* $-1$ *and* $1$). But that's enough to prove that they're equal -- you don't need to know, a priori, that they also agree on values outside that interval.

So it looks to me as if your problem book has an error.